# Visual Studio Missing Warnings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, warnings

Anyone find where when you open a certain solution (that contains multiple projects) and compile that you're not seen some warnings that your colleagues see when compiling the exact same solution at the exact same state?  The code is the same.

I depend highly on the warnings as a shortcut to find unused methods, etc.  But I get nothing during compile..  only a couple based on references to user controls, etc.

Comment: Some specifics about the warnings might be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just guessing here...  When you first build a solution, it has to compile everything.  In that case all warnings come up.  If you run build for a second time, it will only compile what has changed, using the previously compiled (cached) assemblies whenever it can.  In that case the code that doesn't get compiled doesn't show warnings.  If you want to see all warnings again, do a Rebuild from the Build menu which will force all the code to recompile and thus show the warnings.

Comment: Good idea, but is probably not only reason. I have the case where the warnings of a project shows up only when Gendarme (http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme) adds a warning, else none. So if Gendarme warns me of one item, I get like ten in total. If Gendarme doesn't wanr, I get 0 warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your compiler warning level is not as strict as your collegues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Isn't that information defined in the project file? I assumed that he is using the same project file as his coworker.